# Is there a limit to audio file size java can play?

Tags: java, swing, audio

I'm writing a program to loop an audio file on java (BlueJ) Continuously when a button is pressed. My code is working fine for Wav Audio files less than 1Mb,but not for anything of size greater than 1mb. Is there a limit to the size of the file I can play? and if so, how can I work around this? Any help would be great, thanks. Here is my code:-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
public class sound
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        JButton button = new JButton("Button name");
        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new AL());
        frame.show(true);
    }
    public static class AL implements ActionListener
    {
        public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            music();
        }
    }
    public static void music()
    {
        AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
        AudioStream BGM;
        AudioData MD;
        ContinuousAudioDataStream loop = null;
        try
        {
            BGM= new AudioStream(new FileInputStream(file name));
            MD = BGM.getData();
            loop=new ContinuousAudioDataStream(MD);
        }          
        catch(IOException error){}
        MGP.start(loop); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `import sun.audio.*;` Don't use the completely undocumented `sun` classes that might disappear in another manufacturer's VM or even the next release.  Java has provided [Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) since 1.3! Oh, and your IDE has *nothing* to do with this, so that tag is redundant.

Comment: There is no limit on the size, my music player plays files with sizes of 100s of Mb. As Andrew says you need to use the Java Sound APIs and not  sun.audio.*

Comment: Many people use [BasicPlayer](http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/api.html) for the player